# How can I create an array based on values from different array Python Numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have an numpy array `x` (it is a signal). I call a function to find peaks inside `x` and it is returned the index  of where the peaks are. I then take the values around the peaks(+/-90) and save them
in another array

```
 x= x.flatten() 
 peaks, _ = find_peaks(x, distance=180,height=0.70)
 R1_interval = peaks-90
 R2_interval = peaks+90
 z = np.vstack((R1_interval,R2_interval)).T
 z=z.flatten()
```

This is how the first value from array `x` look like:

```
[0.25687721, 0.25985362, 0.26261497, 0.26498313, 0.26681214, 0.2680001, 0.26849836, 0.2683168]
```

This is an example from the array from the first *5000* samples of peaks from `x`:

```
[-13,  167,  280,  460,  572,  752,  856, 1036, 1141, 1321, 1425, 1605, 1719, 1899, 1954, 2134, 2312, 2492, 2616, 2796, 2907, 3087, 3192, 3372, 3469, 3649, 3772, 3952, 4080, 4260, 4376, 4556, 4674, 4854]
```

If I take this code `x[z[1]:z[2]]` I can print the values from a single beat from my signal. My problem is that I want to create a new array that stores every single beat from array `x` and the data of the beat are in a single index.

The desired result would be to have `ar1[0]` equal to `x[z[1]:z[2]]` and so for all beats in `x`. How should I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you right, you already have the peaks in `x`. And all the index boundaries for each `[-90, 90]` window around those peaks are in `z`.

It seems you want to retrieve the values by shifting the array by *1*, so that `ar1[0] := x[z[1]:z[2]]`, `ar1[1] := x[z[3]:z[4]]`... So we'll work with `z[1:-1]`.

Additionaly we have to loop through the indices two by two. Still with indexing: `z[1:-1:2]` will go over `z`'s even indices while `z[2:-1:2]` will go over `z`'s odd indices. You can zip both lists together and construct your final result:

```
[x[a:b] for a, b in zip(z[1:-1:2], z[2:-1:2])]
```

Comment: I couldn't thank you more. It was exactly what i needed